# overheating and shutdown problems when adobe flash runs?

Tags: shutdown, overheating, adobe-air

I'm a new user of UBUNTU and using a Dell latitude D630. When I browse to site that have some flash animation (mostly advertisements), the temperature of cores increase dramatically (I check with sensors, in the worse case it was 104C for one core and 93 for the other core) and if I don't close the website it will shutdown the laptop. Do you have any suggestion or solution for that?

PS: as an example for crashing sites you can see "tabnak.ir", a news website with lots of ads.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also, have you checked "enable hardware acceleration"? This can be found by right-clicking the Flash window and selecting "Settings..."

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing you can do except complain to everyone you meet. Adobe pretends the problem does not exist. They blame websites for having settings incorrectly set.

Who in their right mind develops software that intentionally allows developers to set their software in a way that causes overheating. Even the beta version of Flash Player 11.5 continues to have the problem. It happens in Windows as well; it happens in IE9, Chrome and Firefox.

It would be nice if there was somewhere that everybody being affected by this problem could jointly protest Adobe's irresponsibility.

More info on the subject: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4753975#4753975

Also, install a program that shows your computer temp and pause Flash until the temp starts. It's a temporary help but at least in avoids having the computer shutdown or worse a fire.

Comment: When you say install a program that shows computer temp. Can you be more specific on which program and how it will resolve OP's question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Richard. I solved a part of problem by removing and and inserting of the RAM. I already installed sensors for measuring temperature. BTW thanks for your consideration and help.

Answer (score 2):

Not so much as a solution, more of a workaround, but I'll post this here as I don't have the permissions to comment on a question. I hope you don't mind.

Anyway, install 'Adblock plus' to your browser using whichever extension website is available for your browser.
Then set to disable all of the embedded flash applets that are displayed on the website.

If you are against doing this due to not wanting to harm the owner by disabling adverts, just remember that it's those ads that are harming *you* and your web browsing experience. So don't feel bad for doing so.

I hope this helps in any way.
Sorry for not having a real solution.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but what about, for example, when I want to see a movie on youtube? It also uses adobe flash I think and the same story happens.

Comment: @hamid - Good point. If I were you, I'd enable the YouTube HTML5 video player. Just opt-in and that should be fine. As for other video hosts, I'm unsure, sorry. I'm just a layman.